# How do I measure for a toilet rough-in?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Is my thinking correct - If I measure from the wall to the bolt cap of my current toilet, which is 12", that means I have a 12" rough-in.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  12" is the most common toilet setback in the US.  I've seen a few 10"s and seen listings for 14" but both are not common.

Comment: To add: typically tank type toilets are 12" and flush valve toilets are 10".

Comment: I put in an upscale Kohler a few years back and it could convert between all three with an internal plastic discharge reroute.